# Highcharts - bar chart - show series name under bar

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and have a vertical bar chart, with columns grouped by category. I have the category name showing, and moved to the top. I'd like to get the series name under each bar as well. Is there a way I can do this?

Here's what my chart looks like now, with how I would like it to be in Red
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `dataLabels` to get the wanted result:

```
series: [{
    data: [3, 2, 1],
    dataLabels: [{
        enabled: true
    }, {
        enabled: true,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        inside: true,
        format: '{point.series.name}',
        y: 20
    }]
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qfx8vg9u/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.DataLabelsOptionsObject#format